# Is Amazon S3 storage a well-specified standard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, specifications

I have seen several storage products advertised as "S3-compatible".

Is there a well-defined specification available for these compatible products and if so, which things are specified?

For example, is there a well-defined REST API? Eventual consistency guarantees? Availability of webhooks?

I understand that different vendors make different business decisions and implementation choices on these products so I'd like to know this distinction and whether "S3-compatible" has a meaning other than exactly "sort of like the product Amazon sells, or used to sell on the last time we checked".

Answer (score 3):

"S3-compatible" typically means "you can use any tools that work with S3, but point them to us and it will work fine".

This includes using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with a different endpoint (and a different set of credentials, of course).

The [Amazon S3 REST API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Type_API_Reference.html) is well-defined and has effectively become an industry standard.